# Is there any way to enable the bash to search subdirectory to find a executable?

Tags: linux, bash

I have just built some software on my computer and installed them. After a short period of time, I found files under /usr/local/bin hard to manage because I can't tell which software does each file belong, thus it'll be hard for me to uninstall them or change them(probably their name).

In order to do this, I think the most convenient way is to put softwares in separate directory under `/usr/local/`, but just doing that isn't enough for bash to work.

The first solution I thought of is adding wildcard `/usr/local/*/bin` to the `PATH` variable in `.bashrc`. But it didn't work.

The second solution I thought of is using overlayfs. But I think that's too much for this, and will incur extra overhead.

So is there any way to do this?

My computer is `Debian 9.4, linux kernel 4.9, gcc 6.3`.

Comment: What's wrong with using a directory like `/usr/local/bin` (or any other, if this is already occopied) and add it to $PATH?

Comment: It's hard to uninstall softwares in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software which isn't installed by regular means often goes in `/opt`.

To make the commands available in bash you can add the directory with the executables to the path **without wildcards** (which somehow means one entry for each software you add).

Another solution is to add a short startup script or a soft link to the executable in your `~/bin` (your `~/bin` is usually included in the path if it exists).

Comment: Thx. Added to the answer. Sometimes the script is useful anyway (LOCALE, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, debug/log options...).